# How to make a countdown timer that a custom control

Tags: vb.net, controls

I am trying to create a count down timer control that I will be adding to a bigger project later. The control I am trying to make is a countdown timer that is given an initial value of 60 secs but also allows the user to change that value if needed. I am doing this in Visual Studio using Visual Basics.

```
Public Class UserControl1
    Dim timeTick As Integer
    Dim min As Integer
    Dim setSecs As Integer = 60
    Dim sec As Integer = 120
    Private Sub UserControl1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Timer.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick
        sec -= 1
        min = sec % 60
        Label1.Text = min & " : " & sec
        If sec < 60 Then
            min = 1 + timeTick

            Label1.Text = min & " : " & sec
        End If
    End Sub
    Property HowLong As Integer
        Get
            Return setSecs
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            setSecs = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Set your Timer Interval to something less than one second; I used 250.

Then store the time in the future that is XXX seconds away, representing your countdown duration.

At each tick, simply subtract the current time from the stored future time to get a TimeSpan.  Update your label with the TimeSpan value using ToString().

When the HowLong property is changed, update the target time and restart your timer...easy peesy.

All together, it'd look something like this:

```
Public Class UserControl1

    Private target As DateTime
    Private setSecs As Integer = 60

    Private Sub UserControl1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        target = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(HowLong)
        Timer.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick
        Dim ts As TimeSpan = target.Subtract(DateTime.Now)
        If ts.TotalMilliseconds > 0 Then
            Label1.Text = "-" & ts.ToString("mm\:ss")
        Else
            Label1.Text = "00:00"
            Timer.Stop()
        End If
    End Sub

    Property HowLong As Integer
        Get
            Return setSecs
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            setSecs = value
            Timer.Stop()
            target = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(HowLong)
            Timer.Start()
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

The authors response:

> Technically your way will work to I will post my solution below I did
>   it slightly differently. – Thomas

From my comments on the authors own submission:

> The problem with this type of approach is that the Timer control is
>   not accurate. It is only guaranteed to not fire before the interval
>   has transpired. In fact it will almost always fire after the interval
>   with some extra "slop". For short periods (seconds/minutes), you won't
>   notice. For longer periods (hours), you will, as the accumulated slop
>   becomes bigger as time passes. Whether this matters is completely
>   dependent upon your application. – Idle_Mind

Technically speaking, here's a quick example of how inaccurate simply incrementing/decrementing a counter using a 1 second Timer can be:

```
' Timer1.Interval was set to 1000 (timer fires every "second")

Private seconds As Integer = 0
Private start As DateTime = DateTime.Now

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    seconds = seconds + 1
    Label1.Text = seconds
    Label2.Text = DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalSeconds
End Sub
```

After only 1 hour and 15 minutes, the counter method on the left is already off by 4 seconds from the actual time that has passed:

[image]

A key advantage of the DateTime/TimeSpan method is that the time calculation is **independent** from the Timer.  That is to say that the frequency at which the Timer fires has no bearing on how accurate the time calculation is.

Comment: Technically your way will work to I will post my solution below I did it slightly differently.

Answer (score 0):

This code below is how I made a simple timer control that countdown from a set value. Also, it has 2 buttons that pause and resume the time. This control will not work if in design mode and the timer interval is set to 1000. If you have any questions about how it works just leave a comment.

```
Public Class UserControl1
Dim timeRemaing As Integer = 60

Private Sub UserControl1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick
    Dim sec As Integer
    Dim mins As Integer
    Dim timerFormat As String
    If Not Me.DesignMode Then
        sec = timeRemaing Mod 60
        mins = timeRemaing \ 60

        If sec < 10 Then
            timerFormat = mins.ToString + ":0" + sec.ToString
        Else
            timerFormat = mins.ToString + ":" + sec.ToString
        End If

        If timeRemaing > 0 Then
            timeRemaing -= 1
            lblTime.Text = timerFormat
        Else
            Timer.Stop()
            lblTime.Text = "The Time has Stop!!!"
        End If
    End If


End Sub
Public Property HowLong As Integer
    Get
        Return timeRemaing
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        If value <= 0 Then
            Timer.Stop()
        ElseIf value > 0 Then
            Timer.Start()
            timeRemaing = value
        End If

    End Set
End Property

Private Sub btnPause_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPause.Click
    Timer.Stop()
End Sub

Private Sub btnResume_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnResume.Click
    Timer.Start()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The problem with this type of approach is that the Timer control is not accurate. It is only guaranteed to not fire before the interval has transpired. In fact it will almost always fire after the interval with some extra "slop".  For short periods (seconds/minutes), you won't notice. For longer periods (hours), you will, as the accumulated slop becomes bigger as time passes.  Whether this matters is completely dependent upon your application.

Comment: Thomas, see the edits below my original post as to why this isn't a very accurate approach.

Comment: I see what you are doing but why would I need to use Datetime.now variable if I have a default value of 60 seconds already set and I made a property for the user to change the seconds if needed?

Comment: Re-read my whole post above to see why. It clearly shows the reason...